# Coordinates of the displayed part of an image in Qt

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

How can I know the coordinates of the displayed part of an image in the Qgraphicsview in QT ?

Comment: Maybe you can try `QPointF QGraphicsItem::scenePos() const`.

Comment: @Aleph0 Thanks for the reply. Let me check it